# Raspberry PI changing IP every 30 minutes (+/-)

Tags: networking, ip, raspberry-pi, http, hostname

Please don't judge, I'm a newbe But I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this, and I can't find one that I will suit me:

My PI keeps changing IP while on. I did not turn my router off, I did not restart my PI, but it started at the ip: 192.168.0.188 and in less than two hours it is at the IP: 192.168.0.192, it passed through the IPs ending with 189, 190 and 191 within this timeframe.

Now, why is that important to me? It is for a project where I have to simulate a product that would be donated to lots of people, the raspberry being the 'heart' of this product. Here is the scope: I need to connect to this product through another device, but I cannot use the internet. I need to use only the network where both devices are connected, even if it does not have internet access.

What I did so far: a python/djangle API, and when I run the server AT THE RASPBERRY IP (manage.py runserver 192.168.0.191:8000), I can go on another computer and simulate (using postman) the get response I set by sending a get to the address "http://192.168.0.191:8000/test" (it only returns 'hi'). So ok, I did manage to access it from another device! Nice! However, because the IP keeps changing, I need to keep restarting the server at the right IP, adding the new IP to "ALLOWED_HOSTS" and changing the line of code that sends the GET request. So that sucks, and that is my main problem.

As it's going to be donated to many different people, each one with a different router, I guess I cannot set a static IP to the raspberry. Also, I know you can set a hostname to your raspberry to access it via ssh, but I NEED to access it via HTTP protocol... (i'm trying to learn that too) and I do not understand how a hostname would help me in this dynamic situation. Also, I could not demand that these people who are receiving the product configure their router as I need so the product works.

It would be awesome if I could just freeze the IP on the raspberry once it connected to the network until it's disconnected or it's turned off. Then it would be okay for me to look for the new IP and set things up again, no problem. If there is a universal solution, such as "oh, no, you can set a hostname and access it anywhere and run your server on this hostname and not worry about IP ever by doing A, B and C" it would be even more awesome, but I've searched so much I'm losing hope on that option.

PS: I also had a look into SAMBA but apparently it would only help with the connection with a windows / unix device. I do not know if I can use it with an Android or iOS Client, which would be necessary.

Comment: Hi Laura, welcome to SU.  DHCP is the process used to give an IP to a device.  If it is changing frequently, it is likely that there is a short "lease" given to the IP in dhcp (this says how long a device can keep the IP).  Having it so short indicates a problem or misconfiguration. However, if you want it static, you would reserve the IP in dhcp. This requires access to the router configuration.  Do you have access?

Comment: yes, as Paul was saying, the IP is set by the router. The PI will ask, and get what it is given. Go into your router settings and look in the network DHPC section. If you are lucky you'll see a list of current clients and their IPs and be able to identify the PI. In this case, look in the router DHCP settings for a way to make this one device have a static IP. Also, look for the IP lease setting and make it more reasonable, like 2-3 days.

Comment: My computer, which was connected to the same network as the raspberry, didn't change it's IP once though.. So is it really the router's configuration or could it be the raspberry's?

Comment: it's common for PCs to request the same IP they were just using when they refresh a DHCP lease.  It's possible the Pi is not doing this.  I'd still be checking lease duration in the DHCP settings in your router.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the Pi from a Windows/MacOS/iOS/Android machine, you can use Bonjour mDNS to avoid using the raw IP address.

See [this article:](https://www.howtogeek.com/167190/how-and-why-to-assign-the-.local-domain-to-your-raspberry-pi/)

> sudo apt-get update
>     sudo apt-get upgrade
>     sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon

Then, if using Windows, make sure to install [Bonjour Print Service](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999).
Now, when you open any connection to the Pi (browser, ssh, etc) you will be able to connect using **raspberrypi.local** instead of the raw IP address.

Note: I have tested this method on every machine type *except Android* but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13147094/4438477) suggests it will work.